# settings not saved after reboot

Tags: reboot, system-settings

When I reboot or shut down all my settings are gone. Background picture, launcher items, keyboard settings.

When I log out and log in, everything is fine.

I use an encrypted home folder that has to be mounted extra by executing:

```
ecrypt-mount-private,
```

after booting, reaching the login screen, switching to the console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), login from console 1, switch back to the GUI login screen and then login normally.

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3973632k,nr_inodes=993408,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=799088k,mode=755)
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset,clone_children)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=12407)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=799084k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/home/ith/.Private on /home/ith type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=9ee17501bfe7deb9,ecryptfs_sig=bd06b4279edca158,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** You need to ensure your home folder stays mounted until after your settings are saved.  How do you mount your home folder?  Please [edit] your question to reflect this crucial information.

Comment: Do you need username and password also? ;)

Comment: **:P**  Definitely no UID/PWD needed! **;-)** Did you mean `ecryptfs-mount-private`?  What version of Ubuntu are you using?  What happens if you log out and then shut down?

Comment: ubuntu 16.10; I just tested log out, shut down, restart. All settings gone.

Comment: So when you log out and log in and then shut down everything is kept and when you log out and shut down everything is gone?  Where is your home directory mounted?

Comment: /home/xxx/.Private on /home/xxx type ecryptfs  I think ubuntu detects my home directory when logging in by console. Then I mount with ecryptfs and get a new home ...

Comment: no, when I shut down everything is gone.

Comment: post a `mount` from console and from your user into your question, please.

Comment: Where does ubuntu 16.10 store system settings? When you click your username in the login screen, the background picture is automatically shown. The sys settings are therefore not in the home directory.